# Solution techniques to the Einstein Field Equations

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, computational-physics, software

Consider the EFEs $$R_{\mu\nu}-\frac12Rg_{\mu\nu}=\kappa T_{\mu\nu} \implies G_{\mu\nu}=\kappa T_{\mu\nu}.$$ The Einstein Field Equations are a set of highly couples non-linear hyperbolic PDEs, which implies that solutions are hard to find do to their non-linearity. I have attempted to solve the equations via Mathematica, but to no avail. What are some techniques used, to reduce the equations such that they can be solvable? Is there an alternative program that can solve such sets of PDEs?

EDIT: We are looking at rest frame of a perfect fluid for our SEM tensor. I am looking for techniques to solve for perfect fluids. Our boundary conditions are all elements of the metric go to zero as r goes to infinity.

Comment: This question is far too general. What sort of specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Which package are you using in Mathematica?

Comment: Are you looking for analytic or numerical solutions?

Comment: Xact tensor package and looking for analytic solutions. The stress energy tensor is a perfect fluid in the specific problem.

Comment: Is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_fluid) what you need?

Comment: Ok, I usually use the GREAT.m package for analytic solutions

Comment: @KP99 Can the GREAT.m package solve for more then the vacuum and Kerr equations?

Comment: Well, you have to first assume a particular form of metric and then you can use the package to directly calculate Christoffel symbols, Riemann tensor, Ricci tensor, Einstein tensor etc. You can then solve for the metric components corresponding to some particular stress-energy tensor

Comment: Yes I know that process. I can calculate all the tensors, although the results I get cant get solved in mathematica for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

It makes no sense to try to solve these equations given just the equations. The field equations relate the distribution of matter in some region of space, given by the energy momentum tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$, to the curvature of space at that region, given by the Einstein tensor $G_{\mu\nu}$. You need to specify the energy momentum tensor for a specific case, a specific matter distribution, to solve the field equations. It's not difficult to solve for particular cases which involve different kinds of symmetry. The Schwarzschild solution isn't particularly complicated, for example, but I won't bother going into the details of any particular case. The point is you can't solve for the metric given just the equation without any other conditions or any matter distributions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general, exact solution to the Einstein Field Equations.  As a comparison, lets look at Schrodinger's Equation.  Schrodinger's Equation is often the first non-trivial differential equation encountered in the physics curriculum:
$$i\hbar\partial_t \Psi = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\Psi+V\Psi.$$
If you want to solve this differential equation you first must know what the potential $V$ is.  In introductory QM we assume $V = V(x)$ is constant in time.  This means we can use separation of variables to isolate the time parts of the equation from the space parts, resulting in two ODEs that can be solved.

In general the potential could vary in time, too.  If $V=V(x,t)$ is not separable, then the whole equation is not separable, and we need to use a different method to solve it.  In any intro QM textbook you'll see that even for static $V$'s that don't change in time the method to solve for a particle in a 1D square well differs from the method to solve a 1D quantum harmonic oscillator.

In addition to specifying the potential a full solution also depends on boundary conditions.  The same potential with different boundary conditions will result in different solutions.  The real world often gives us boundary conditions. For example for an electron bound in a hydrogen atom, we know $\Psi\rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$, and $\Psi\rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow 0$.

Even though we can find exact analytic solutions to particular cases there is no way to write down a closed form, analytic, general solution for all cases.

The Einstein Field Equations work the same way.  In order to find a solution, first you must specify $T_{\mu\nu}$.  Even after you specify $T_{\mu\nu}$, you need to specify the boundary conditions.  Like with the Schrodinger Equation, often times the real world provides the boundary condition, e.g. $g_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow \eta_{\mu\nu}$ as $r\rightarrow\infty$.  Which method works to find a solution will depend on which $T_{\mu\nu}$, you pick.

Comment: $g_{\mu\nu} \to 0$ is wrong, didi you mean $g_{\mu\nu} \to$ Minkowski at large distances?

Comment: @ApolloRa, yes, good catch